# "with" is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting an identifier

Tags: mysql, database, recursion, syntax, triggers

I have this trigger which is running fine in my localhost but when i want to deploy it to the server , it gives me this error. ( "with" is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting an identifier.) Any idea how to get rid of this please?

```
with recursive cte as (
    select name as name, left(name, 1) as val, 1 as idx
    union all
    select name, substring(name, idx + 1, 1), idx + 1 
    from cte 
    where idx < char_length(name)
)
select group_concat(ascii(val)  order by idx separator '') ascii_word from cte into result;
```

so name is a string. It takes the string converts it into characters - ascii characters and then merge it at the end.

Comment: Looks like you need to upgrade the MySQL version on your server, only MySQL 8+ supports CTEs

Comment: I am using hostgator and as i searched i cannot upgrade the mysql version there. Any idea how can i make this work with the older version? by replacing this cte with something maybe?